# Start a loop with random value then cycle the whole range

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

**First:** I am generating a random value under the range from `0` to `30`, for example.

**Second:** choose `18` from the range.

**Third:** Need to cycle from `18 - 30` and from `17 - 0` **in one loop.**

Optional: The range can be changed, it was an example. The main thing that I need to cycle it in one loop, beginning with generated number in the range.  And it is not important, in which order I can start the cycle. The thing is that I have to start the loop with the random number from the range.

I have tried only with two loops, like this:

```
int low;
int high;
/* Generate a random value from low to high*/

for (i =  middleRand  ; i < high; i++)
{ 
       /* TODO*/
}
for ( i = middleRand - 1; i > low; i--)
{
      /* TODO*/
}
```

But it is not what I really need, and I'd like to use **only one loop**.

**The example:**

I have two points which create in the parallel way.
The first point starts its loop with `0 - 29`, the another one `0 - 29`.
But my goal is that the first point starts with the random number from the range (`18`), the second one starts under `11`. But the all two points need to cycle the whole range.

Comment: `from 18 - 30 and from 17 - 0` - it's not a cycle. First fix this. Then try to do this with 1 for-loop for range `[0; n)`. You will have to use `... % n`. Then generalize this for all ranges.

Comment: Is there any good reason for having single loop? Sounds like a http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @MayurK, sounds like HW.

Comment: @dyukha        No, it is not HW. Do you need to read a specific things, why I ask a question? I have tried to ask a simple question, if I can get some answer, I will take for my solving the problem. Thank you for your help. I will think about your suggestion upper.

Comment: So can you clarify, do you need to *cycle* (so it's `18->30` then `0->17`) or do you need `18->30` then `17->0`? In the latter case my comment is not applicable and you should also remove the word *cycle* from the problem.

Comment: Can you please clarify a little bit more your problem? Explain it more with words what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @M.K  tried ti explain it more.

Comment: @JustMe: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear.
But I can say that if I understand your question, then you can do:

```
int low;
int high;
int random_val = rand() % (high -low) + low;

for (int i = 0; i < high; i++) {
    if (i > random_val) {
         // low
    } else {
         // high
    }
}
```

you can replace //low by the code for the low loop, and //high for the high loop

Comment: As per question, middleRand to low should happen in decremented order. But as you mentioned, the question is not clear :(

Comment: @Hamza Ince                     I need the same code in `low` and `high` parts but start a loop with the random value.

Comment: I changed my code, now the random value is between high and low, and in the loop I check if i is bigger than the random value

Comment: @JustMe If the problem is trying to minimise lines of code by merging two loops into one, you should look at using functions instead. (Your question seems like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/). It's quite impossible/difficult to merge those two loops into one sequentially.)

Comment: well its definitely possible but one would need to change `i++` to something like `i+=k` and `k` being a value which will either be `1` or `-1`, depending on the current loop body. Its a very classical school exercise / homework.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```c
int low = 0;                      // start of range, included
int high = 30;                    // end of range, included
int span = high - low + 1;        // number of values in the range
int start = low + rand() % span;  // random initial value
for (int i = 0; i < span; i++) {  // generate `span` values
    int value = low + (i + start - low) % span;
    // use value for this iteration
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, what you try to do is to manage several control variables of the loop at the same time.  There's a C idiom for that:

```
int i, j, k;
for (i = 18, j = 17, k = 1; i < 30; i++, j--, k <<= 1) {
     /* bla bla */
}
```

In this case, `i` will be `18, 19, ...., 29`, `j` will be `17, 16, ..., 7`, and  `k` will be `1, 2, 4, 8, ...`.

There's one thing you cannot do with this approach... is to have different ways to end the loop, depending on the different control variables.  In your case, you say that the first variable goes from `18` to `30` which is 12 passes through the loop, while the second goes from `17` to `0` which is 18 passes through the loop, you'll need to decide when to stop, because **there's only a loop now**.